grafana multi graph clickhouse
I have a table in clickhouse with the data
log_date     log_time     camera_name          count
2024-12-27   2024-12-27   14:03:26.036 +0700   ВК-33 16
2024-12-27   2024-12-27   14:03:26.036 +0700   ВК-32 16

I want to group by camera_name and display the count for each group on one graph (Like in the example from the documentation only without fill and with dots).
My query looks like this
SELECT
  toTimeZone(logtime, 'Asia/Bangkok') as t,  
  camera_name,
  SUM(count) as frame_count
FROM $table
GROUP BY camera_name, t
ORDER BY t

But the graph looks as follows. Only one line is drawn. Tell me how to be

which plugin do you use for connect to clikckhouse? https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-grafana/ or https://github.com/grafana/clickhouse-datasource/ ? which version of plugin? which grafana-server version do you use?
